Can't solve "ubuntu curthooks crashed with curtininstallerror"
I have been using Ubuntu without any problem in VM since 2023, and today was my first attempt to install it on my Laptop. I was installing Ubuntu and the installation was interrupted by this error tilted "curthooks crashed with curtininstallerror" and it starts running the lite version that you can try of Ubuntu. I read some things about this error, but they all seem solved in the last versión for desktop. What information can I post here to give you more information about the error?
Mi PC is an Asus ROG M16, RTX 3060, Ryzen 9.

Are you trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop? or Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server?  as you only mention the release (24.04).   that error can occur with both ubuntu-desktop-installer and subiquity, but you've not said which installer you attempted to use; though you did mention desktop having fixes, but were not specific

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 24.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 24.04. I think it was partially installed, beaches when a reboot the PC without the USB installation media, it boots Ubuntu. So I don't really know what might work or not. I thought that maybe the error was caused because a had the BIOS/UEFI not updated. So, I tried installing Windows again to update de BIOS/UEFI, but now the tool for installation does not detect my SSD. Can the Ubuntu installation change something about the SSD that now the windows installation tool does not detect the SSD?
